# Validations on C++ (Console)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, validation, console-application

Scenario 1 :

The input is taken in as a character array [20] and is saved onto a *.dat file.

I need to validate the size of the array, check the if there are any special characters,numeric and letter's case sensitivity.

since it's not a string cannot I use strlen to validate the length. If not is it possible to use `.length  or size_t / sizeof` method

Scenario 2 :

Need to validate Age , Id and Phone number which are integers in a struct.(also saved onto a *.dat file)

For an Example:

```
struct patient{

    int pId, age ,contactNo;
}

void input(){

 patient obj;
 if ((int)obj.age<=65){
 //Some Code 
  }
}
```

The Above method did not work.

I need to validate the age with a set age limit like the above. pId should not be more than four digits and phone number will be 10 digits with out "-" in between and should only allow numeric input.

Is there any possible way of doing the above scenarios. If it possible please give me an example ...

Comment: 1) Have you tried something? Show us then please 2) 1. It seems than your solution to validate age is correct, whats the problem ?  2. *10 digits with out "-"* - `int` cannot have this "-" and there can be an overflow of `int`. So what the problem is exactly? You don't know how to read or parse data or validate it or you have some specific problem in code?

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych Hi ! thanks for your time. The age problem like answered below it has that issue. The phone number format should not be in 1-908-528-5656 instead something like 0112729729. The phone number should be validated accord to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear (at least) to me what you ask for in Scenario 1.

Scenario 2:

- You need a semicolon after your struct definition
- You should removed the typecast: `(int)obj.age<=65` should be `obj.age<=65`, as it is already an `int`
- With respect to `pId`, just check if it under 10000
- For `contactNo`  you need a `uint64_t` otherwise it cannot hold ten arbitrary digits.

It may also be a good idea to make your `age` and `pId` variables `unsigned int` instead of `int`, this way you remove the possibility of negative `age` and `pId` with a minus.

You can construct an object of type `patient` like this:

```
patient obj{1234, 47, 1234567};
```

Comment: Thanks! "For contactNo you need a uint64_t otherwise it cannot hold ten arbitrary digits." I don't understand that one....

Comment: The maximum value for an `int` is 2147483647, for `unsigned int` it is 4294967295. That is, if you use `int` the left-most digit cannot be more than 2 (4 for `unsigned int`) if you have ten digits.

Comment: For a type to have 10^10 (ten digits) possible values it needs at least 34 bits (`ceil(log2(pow(10,10)))`), i.e., an 32 bit `int` cannot hold it.

Comment: Thanks Once Again..... yes but can I directly compare to value like    `obj.age<=65` because when I do that it loops through the condition and exits.... with a press any key to continue ......

Comment: Yes, `obj.age<=65` is completely valid, and will for the example in the answer be true.

Comment: Thank you! I am unable to mark it as the answer as I don't have enough reps....